# directly print with php

Tags: php

I try to print directly with php library php_printer.dll, my problem is that my printer print strange words instead of PDF file.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php

    $printer = ("Epson Printer");
    if($ph = printer_open($printer))
    {
       $file = file_get_contents('receipt.pdf', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
       printer_write($ph, $file);
       printer_close($ph);
    }
    else "Couldn't connect...";
    ?>
```

**UPDATE**
Now i try with this code on Windows 7, but print not start:

```
shell_exec( 'print /d:EPSON MFC-J265W c:\file.txt');
```

Comment: Well, yes... HTML is interpreted by browsers. There is no browser involved here.

Comment: I bet there is a HTML compatible printer. Something that turns HTML into postscript and then you can direct it to a file or printer. It's probably hard to find that on the windows operating system.

Comment: Is [html2ps](http://www.tufat.com/script19.htm) what you want?

Comment: um.. you're talking about parsing the php code and you have a .pdf file in your example. So you have PHP and HTML within PDF and you expect that to print like it looks on the browser? You do realize that on the browser, it first goes through the web server, PHP interpreter and then HTML rendering engine?

Comment: i have change my function for print directly with PDF file. Now the printer print strange words and not correct pdf file.

Answer (score 1):

Well... your contents consists of all tags and you are giving a `text` type output to your printer.

Of course it is going to print like that.

If you want to do a straight print with only the text `Write a test 20012-10-24`, then you probably need to create it in another PHP file, read the output with, ie, `file_get_contents` and then do your printing with the results received.

---

Now printing a PDF file is a totally different issue. You can print it via shell execution:

```
shell_exec( 'lpr /path/to/file/filename.pdf' );
```

Or with a PHP class found [here](http://www.nongnu.org/phpprintipp/):

```
require_once( 'PrintIPP.php' );

$ipp = new PrintIPP();
$ipp->setHost( 'localhost' );
$ipp->setPrinterURI( '/printers/epson' );
$ipp->setData( '/path/to/file/filename.pdf' );

$ipp->printJob();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, how make simulated "<br>" tags?

Comment: shell_exec( 'print /d:EPSON MFC-J265W c:\file.txt');

Comment: shell_exec( 'print /d:EPSON MFC-J265W c:\file.txt') not working for me