# print generated file.txt using php / laravel

Tags: php, html

so i have this code for generate file.txt

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("test.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

then i show it on textarea like this:

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="50">
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('./test.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
echo $file;
?>
</textarea>
```

i need to print the file test.txt directly using button in php. How can i do this in php / laravel framework?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

**1** instead of showing the textarea, just show a link:

```
<a href="print_test_txt.php">print text.txt!</a>
```

**2** create a new file called **print_test_txt.php** and populate it with this php

**3**

```
<?php
  $file = file_get_contents('./test.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
  echo $file;
?>
```

which will output it to the screen so the user can print it.  if you are hoping to print to a known printer, see this solution:

[directly print with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045153/directly-print-with-php)